# how to group resources involved in a specific set of changesets?

Tags: tfs, tfvc

How can I query the tfs history to have this result: ***group the resources involved in a set of changesets?***

What I'm trying to do is understanding which files changed in the last 2 months for example.

I tried on TFS Explorer, but I can obtain the details just from a single changeset. It's the same for TFS Sidekicks. I had no luck with the command line and not even connecting directly to the database.

Does someone knows a smart way to get that result?

Comment: So you want a list of all files changed in the last 2 months?

Comment: yes..but really I couldn't find a straight way to get such a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure how to get the `VersionTo` and `VersionFrom` so I am just doing from version `100` to `Latest` in here. You could you Source Control Explorer to do a View History and get your `VersionFrom` and `VersionTo`.

Here's a snippet of code that uses the TFS API. You will need to add some references to `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.*` assemblies to get it to build.

```
using (var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(CollectionAddress)))
{
    var server = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

    var changes = 
        server.QueryHistory(
          "$/Project/Main",
          VersionSpec.Latest,
          0,
          RecursionType.Full,
          "",
          VersionSpec.ParseSingleSpec("100", ""), //From ??
          VersionSpec.Latest,                     //To ??
          100,
          true,
          true)
    .Cast<Changeset>()
    .SelectMany(changeset => changeset.Changes.Select(change => change.Item.ServerItem));
}
```

Comment: I didn't consider using the TFS api yet. It was really helpful, thanks.

Comment: @Diego that's my First Place to go. I use LinqPad so I can get the results straight away.